# Unable to install Python3 packages on Debian based OS

Tags: apt, software-installation, kali-linux, python3

I am using Kali Linux (based on Debian) and below is the output of the uname -a command

```
Linux kali 5.3.0-kali2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.3.9-3kali1 (2019-11-20) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I want to install the following python3 packages but apt-get cannot find them:

```
python3-geoip
python3-whois
```

Below is the output when I try to install python3-whois package using apt-get command

```
# sudo apt-get install python3-whois
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3-whois
```

I already ran the following commands to update apt-get

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

The version of Python installed is 3.7.5 and python3 is located in the path: /usr/bin/python3

**Update**:

Below are the contents of my /etc/apt/sources.list file

```
# 

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 2019.4 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20191125-10:47]/ kali-last-snapshot contrib main non-free

#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 2019.4 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20191125-10:47]/ kali-last-snapshot contrib main non-free

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.

deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

I even checked the apt update logs here: /var/log/apt/history.log and there is no information corresponding to the apt-get install commands I ran.

It seems like Kali Linux is not configured with the apt-get repositories by default?

How can I install the above python3 packages?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you run any apt commands? Does `apt search python3-` return anything? Your **/etc/apt/sources.list** file is exactly the same as mine (the default, btw) and every command you've referenced works. Maybe your apt database is hosed.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming python's own [`pip` package manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pip_(package_manager)) is installed and configured correctly, you may try

```
pip install python-geoip-python3
pip install python-whois
```

to install the missing packages. Depending on the installation, the binary may also be called `pip3`.

Comment: Apparently pip is not installed and I can't install it using apt-get either. I have updated my post with more information, please check. It seems that the default repositories are not configured on Kali Linux.

Answer (score 1):

My thoughts is that Kali is based but is not using the Debian repositories itself, the package exist at https://packages.debian.org/sid/amd64/python3-whois. 
So as last chance you can download it manually and install it but a log of `apt update` is the fest way to check if is using those repositories.

Comment: I have updated the description and included some more details. Please check. It includes the contents of the sources.list file for apt and also the apt update log. Thanks.

Comment: It is confirmed that you don't have the debian repository so you cannot download from them. You should check what Kali says about debian official repo